# Woocommerce : cart total shows zero for 1 item

Tags: wordpress, woocommerce, cart

I have created a link in the header of my site to the cart with the current totals.

It is supposed to show the current total of the cart and the number of items contained in the cart, in this manner :

[icon] 1.20 € - 1 article

However, the value is only correctly calculated when in the cart page.  On the homepage, for example, it will only display like this :

[icon] 0.00 € - 1 article

This is how I am accessing the values :

```
$count = WC()->cart->cart_contents_count;
WC()->cart->calculate_totals();
if($count > 0)
{
    print "<a class='cart-contents' href='" . WC()->cart->get_cart_url();
    print "' title='Voir votre panier'>";
    print WC()->cart->get_total();
    print " - " . sprintf(_n('%d article', '%d articles', $count, 'woothemes'), $count);
    print "</a>";
}
```

If I call `WC()->cart->get_cart_total();`, this will show the price exclusive of tax, even if I force prices include tax.

How can I get the correct value consistently across the site ?

Answer (score 3):

```
global $woocommerce;

$amount = $woocommerce->cart->cart_contents_total+$woocommerce->cart->tax_total;
```

You can also convert $amount in float value as per your requirement.

Answer (score 2):

I had the same issue so I went through the WooCommerce code. In the function `WC()->cart->calculate_totals()` in the class `WC_Cart` since some time ago there is a following condition

```
// Only calculate the grand total + shipping if on the cart/checkout
if ( is_checkout() || is_cart() || 
     defined('WOOCOMMERCE_CHECKOUT') || defined('WOOCOMMERCE_CART') )
```

This condition applies to calculating specifically the `total`, I'm not sure why. But this gives you the proper workaround:
On the page where you need to show the total include either one of the following lines of code:

```
define( 'WOOCOMMERCE_CART', true );
```

or

```
define( 'WOOCOMMERCE_CHECKOUT', true );
```

And then perform the function `WC()->cart->calculate_totals();`

Then to get the cart total use either `WC()->cart->total` or `wc_cart_totals_order_total_html()` (for currency symbol)